# Ruby on Rails css assets pipeline organization issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, asset-pipeline

I have to use a certain table styling on only show.html.haml pages of my application.  Specifically, I do not want this styling to be applied to my forms in _form.html.haml partials.  Here are the style elements:

```
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
  }

  td, th {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding:5px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: ellipsis;
  }

  th {
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  }
```

I created a small file called data_tables.css in my app/vendor/assets/web-app-theme/stylesheets directory and included it in my application.js like so:

*= require web-app-theme/data_tables

Trouble is:  It affects not only the tables in my show.html.haml pages (which I want) but also the _form_html.haml partials (which I don't want).  Apparently, there is something I don't fully understand about assets organization.  Here are the contents of my application.css file in the app/assets/stylesheets directory:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require web-app-theme/base
 *= require web-app-theme/style
 *= require web-app-theme/wat_ext
 *= require web-app-theme/data-tables
 *= require formalize
 *= require jquery.ui.core
 *= require jquery.ui.theme
 *= require jquery.ui.tabs
 *= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you declare in manifest is dumped into the single file during assets compilation. The best solution to your problem would be assigning classes to tables you want CSS to affect and changing it accordingly.

Alternatively you can remove this file from manifest and call it from views with `stylesheet_link_tag` like this:

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "web-app-theme/data_tables"%>
```

But it's not something you want to use for small files, since it increases amount of requests to your server over nothing.

Comment: Thank you.  I followed your advice and created a specific class (and associated elements).  This works best.